# Realm Recycler View with multiple sections?

Tags: header, adapter, realm

The title explains it all. I am very new to recycler views, let alone partitioning them into sections. I have looked at some examples as to how to do this, however, most of the examples are used with static data. Is this even possible to do with Realm? For example, I have an object, Schools, and I want to separate this into different sections such as -- nearby, etc. etc. I.e., I want to separate and sort the objects based on certain model properties. Any guidance as to how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview. It is able to create section headers for your Realm data.

Comment: Only if using 2.x 3.x not supported